# Why am I looping back to MainWindow when creating an object in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, class, inheritance, visual-studio-2017

I'm new to programming and learning C# by trying to create a Sudoku game in WPF. At the moment, trying to see if I can display TextBlock (the control that makes up each cell) information by utilizing a Position method that takes row and column coordinates.

However, the MessageBox.Show() command never executes when I launch the code. Stepping through it seems that as soon as it tries to create the Grid object, it immediately jumps back to the public MainWindow() line, and as a result the MessageBox command never happens. One of my suspicions is that it has to do with Grid.cs inheriting from MainWindow, but I thought that was appropriate so I could reference the xaml objects. What else could be causing this loop?

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace Sudoku
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {        
        public MainWindow()
        {            
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeGame();
        }

        private void InitializeGame()
        {
            var Grid = new Grid();
            MessageBox.Show(Grid.Position(2, 5).Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Grid.cs:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Sudoku
{    
    public class Grid : MainWindow
    {        
        /// Returns a TextBlock cell object at a specified row and column coordinate.
        public TextBlock Position(int row, int column)
        {
            return GameGrid.Children
                       .Cast<TextBlock>()
                       .Where(e => System.Windows.Controls.Grid.GetRow(e) == row && System.Windows.Controls.Grid.GetColumn(e) == column)
                       .Single();                        
        }
    }
}
```

In addition, running the code seems to be causing some rapid garbage collection, which I can't understand: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hGCl.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `Grid` is created it inherits from `MainWindow`, which seems to call it again and causing a loop until a stack overflow. Instead, remove the inheritance in Grid.cs and pass `GameGrid` through the `Grid` constructor. (A lot of "Grid" going on! Be careful of ambiguous reference errors)

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
var Grid = new Grid(GameGrid);
```

Grid.cs:

```
public Grid GameGrid;
public Grid (Grid g)
{
    GameGrid = g;
}
```

In addition, the rapid garbage collection is just the program creating the same data over and over again.

Comment: If I'm to reference xaml objects in other non-MainWindow classes, do I also need to pass the relevant objects in via methods as well? It's possible that this is an involved question that would require more information; I just want to know what the scope of my options are.

Comment: You could make those objects public or protected in the MainWindow.xaml.cs and then just directly reference them from Grid by using MainWindow.ObjectName.